# Customize list rendering for pagination

Tags: list, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8

i'm trying to implement infinite scroll in Orchard doing minimal changes.

The script I use need to perfectly identify with a jquery selector the Next page link of pager.

Currently a standard orchard pager renders this way:

```
<li><a href="/OrchardLocal/ricette?page=2">&gt;</a></li>
```

the desiderable rendering is:

```
<li class="next"><a href="/OrchardLocal/ricette?page=2">&gt;</a></li>
```

I tried many ways to override the Pager_Next template but no joy.
The pager is a list and list is done by code. No easy way to override.

A great article the should explain how to do miss some basic part (as to override the whole list for example): 
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/overriding-the-pager-rendering-in-orchard

Right now my workaround was to change the Orchard source CoreShapes.cs for list rendering adding these two lines:

```
if (itemTag != null) {
  if (index == 0)
    itemTag.AddCssClass("first");
  if (index == count - 1)
    itemTag.AddCssClass("last");

  //new lines
  if (index == 1 && count > 2)
    itemTag.AddCssClass("previous");
  if (index == count - 2 && count > 2)
     itemTag.AddCssClass("next");
```

So far it works BUT I do not like it

1) It changes orchard source, this is bad

2) It changes all the lists (and not just pager)

So "How may I override the list for JUST my theme and for JUST pager in a way that a class is added automatically at the Page_Next li tag?"

Thanks

Comment: Use jQuery to add those classes to your desired lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in your Pager.Next.cshtml alternate view:

```
@using System.Web.Routing;
@{
    string text = Model.Value.ToString();
    string action = Model.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues = (RouteValueDictionary)Model.RouteValues;
}

<span><a class="next" href="@Url.Action(action, routeValues)">@text</a></span>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I just removed the span... actually I do not need it :) What I really need was a way to get the actual link and you provide me the perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the answer by joshb is close enough for your needs.
Otherwise I would say almost the same thing.

Change the Pager.Next.cshtml and Pager.Previous.cshtml in your theme, and simply add a way for you to identify the link.

The use jQuery to add the class you need to the parent.

This is by no means an elegant solution, but it will accomplish what you're asking for without changing the core and without affecting other lists.

My test looks like this, just for testing and only for next, but you get the idea.

(Don't use id obviously as it would give you duplicate id's, this is just a quick and dirty example)

**Pager.Next.cshtml** :

```
@{
    var RouteValues = (object)Model.RouteValues;
    RouteValueDictionary rvd;
    if (RouteValues == null) {
        rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }
    else {
        rvd = RouteValues is RouteValueDictionary ? (RouteValueDictionary)RouteValues : new RouteValueDictionary(RouteValues);
    }
}
<a id="pagination-pager-next" href="@Url.Action((string)rvd["action"], rvd)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

And added this at the end of **Pager.cshtml**, but you may have a better place for it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pagination-pager-next").parent().addClass("next");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I maked the reply of joshb as the accepted on just because he was the first one. The use of jquery is nice but adds an extra layer of complexity the I do not need in this context. Having a class on the a tag did the trick anyway. All the best.